# Taylor series of function composition

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm struggling with proving this:

Let $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$ where $g\colon\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ in class $C^{\infty}$. Assuming the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ of $g(t)=P_n$, prove the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ of $f$ is $P_n (x+y)$.

I tried the chain rule and defining $f$ as a composition of $g$ and $h(x,y) = x+y$, as well as using the formula for Taylor series in multiple dimensions, but it comes out really messy and doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $P_n(x+y)$ is a polynomial in the variables $x$ and $y$ whose degree is at most $N$. And\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-P_n(x+y)}{\|(x,y)\|^n}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{g(x+y)-P_n(x+y)}{(x+y)^n}\times\left(\frac{(x+y)}{\|(x,y)\|}\right)^n\\&=0,\end{align}since$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{g(x+y)-P_n(x+y)}{(x+y)^n}=0$$(because $P_n$ is the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ of $g$ at $0$) and $(x,y)\mapsto\frac{(x+y)}{\|(x,y)\|}$ is bounded. Therefore, $P_n(x+y)$ is the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ of $f$ at $(0,0)$.